# How to skip broken Images URL from Prestashop Import?

Tags: php, prestashop, importerror, prestashop-1.6

I'm importing a catalog of products into the Prestashop store, but there is a problem with the image url broken, because the product is show with a default image with interrogation sign.

My idea is to **skip those url and don't use the default unknown image**. Any idea for this??

This is the default image used when image url is broken

[image]

This is a product with some images by default because of lost images

[image]

Comment: Hi, please provide what you have done so far (sample code) so that the community can help you better.

Comment: The idea is just to skip those url using some validation, perhaps in Prestashop 1.6.1.10 Core. But I've no code to show, I'm using a module to import XML named: **Advanced XML & CSV Importer**

Comment: I would recommend looking for the SRC attribute on the image through [XPATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). Then only run the code to import it if it doesn't match the URL of the default image. However, as you have provided no code, I can't say exactly how you should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for contributing with your help. I could do that script but that solution wont be useful because I import the catalog each hour.

I figured out a solution and it was adding some changes to the Import module, so now the module before import an url it checks `file_exists()` and instead of throw a new exception will `do unset()` for that image url so with that is enough for my solution. Thanks all.

THis is the code:

```
// Get images real path, and check exists
    foreach ($images as $key => $img) {
        /*if (preg_match('/:\/\//', $images[$key]->value)) {
            continue;
        }*/

        $url = $images[$key]->value;

        $filename = explode('=',$url)[1];

        $images[$key]->value = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/testimg/'.$filename.'.jpg';

        if (!file_exists($images[$key]->value))
        {
            unset($images[$key]);
            //throw new Exception("File {$images[$key]->value} not found.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Product's images are listed in `ps_image` table. You should do an script that delete all images that table that are not present in `/img/p/` folder.

You could do a image resize in backffoffice images options menu, but I'm not sure if this clean database.

Good luck.